# Find all permitation for list or word list in very long text

Tags: algorithm, string-algorithm

Given the word list = { w1,w2,w3,w1,w2 }

Find all permutations of above word list in long text.

long text list = {This is long text w1 w2 w3  w4 and **w1 w2  w1 w2 w3**.  This yet another long text which does not have permutation because it does not contain all words w1,w2,w2,w2,w2 , but this is permutation **w2 w2 w3 w1 w1**} separated by space

What is most efficient Algorithm to solve this problem?

I thought that of assigning a tuple (unique #, unique prime #) to each unique word in list first {w1 = [101, 5], w2 =  [103, 7],  w3 = [205, 11] }  and calculate sum of for entire list using assigned tuples :   w1 [101 *5] + w2 [ 103 * 7] + w3 [  205 * 11] + w1 [101 *5] + + w2 [ 103 * 7] = 4707

Here is pudo-code:

```
targetSum = 4707;
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0;  i < Text.size(); i++){
     look up (unique #, unique prime #) 
     sum  + = ((unique # * unique prime) ;
     if(  i >  list.size() ){
         sum = sum – (look up (unique #, unique prime # for index 
                ( i – list.size()) and subtract tuple sum)
     }

    if(targetSum = = sum ){
        // this is possible match so hashMap lookup verify  again  that this reagion is actual match.
}
```

}

Is there any better logic or algorithm for this ?

Update :

I was reading further on the Pattern matching Z-Algorithm (Z-Boxes), but I am not able to see how Z-boxes or Z-Array would make it better unless all permutation are know upfront.  Not sure if there is there is any better way ?

Thank you all sharing knowledge.

Thanks,

Bhavesh

Comment: What do you mean by unique #? Is that the number of a certain word you found in the long text? Unique prime is a score for that word?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Do the words have to be contiguous? That is, the text "blah w1 blah w2 blah w3 blah w1 blah w2" would not count?

Comment: @small_data88,   unique # can be increment # (primary key in dictionary of words ).  Find all the permutation of word list in long text.

Comment: @vish4071,  I was trying to find what is best  or optimal approach to this interesting problem.

Comment: @JimMischel,  yes permutation has to be contiguous, but can be any order.  Another approach is to find all permutation of list = { w1,w2,w3,w1,w2 }  and find each form in as  sub-string in long text.  I think this may not be good approach since cost of permutation is high as # words increase.

Answer (score 1):

If the words have to be contiguous, then start by building a dictionary of the words you're looking for, along with their counts. For your example of `[w1, w2, w3, w1, w2]`, the dictionary would contain:

```
{w1, 2}
{w2, 2}
{w3, 1}
```

Call that the incoming dictionary.

Also create an empty dictionary of the same type (i.e. word, count). Call that the outgoing dictionary.

Then, build a queue that's the size of the number of words you're looking for. The queue is initially empty.

Then, you start going through the text, word by word, doing this:

```
for each text_word in text
    if queue.count == number of words
        queue_word = remove word from queue
        if queue_word is in outgoing dictionary
            remove from outgoing
            add to incoming
        end if
    end if

    add text_word to queue
    if text_word is in incoming dictionary
        remove text_word from incoming dictionary
        add text_word to outgoing dictionary
        if incoming dictionary is empty
            you found a permutation
        end if
    end if
```

The only complication here is that "add word to dictionary" and "remove word to dictionary" have to take into account the possibility of multiple occurrences of the same word. So your removal is really something like:

```
count = dictionary[word].Count = 1
if (count == 0)
    dictionary.Remove(word)
else
    dictionary[word].Count = count
```

And adding is similar.

Comment: thanks this approach work well as well with moving window as queue.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of identifying your pattern with primes is good, but the product of distinct primes is unique, not their sum.

You can then use a moving-window approach. Calculate the product of your pattern and the product of the first five words. Then you move the window by dividing off the product from the left and mutiplying to the right. All words not in your pattern have a neutral value of 1.

```
def permindex(text, pattern, start = 0):
    """Index of first permutation of the pattern in text"""

    if len(text) - start < len(pattern):
        return -1

    primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

    value = {}
    goal = 1
    for p in pattern:
        if not p in value:
            value[p] = primes.pop(0)

        goal *= value[p]

    prod = 1
    for t in text[start:start + len(pattern)]:
        prod *= value.get(t, 1)

    i = start

    for j in range(start + len(pattern), len(text)):

        if goal == prod:
            return i

        prod /= value.get(text[i], 1)
        prod *= value.get(text[j], 1)

        i += 1

    if goal == prod:
        return len(text) - len(pattern)

    return -1
```

Applying this to your problem:

```
import re

patt = "w1 w2 w3 w1 w2".split()

text = re.split("\W+", 
        """This is long text w1 w2 w3 w4 and w1 w2 w1 w2 w3. This 
        yet another long text which does not have permutation because 
        it does not contain all words w1,w2,w2,w2,w2 , but this is 
        permutation w2 w2 w3 w1 w1""")

p = permindex(text, patt)
while p >= 0:
    print p, text[p: p + len(patt)]
    p = permindex(text, patt, p + 1)
```

yields:

```
9 ['w1', 'w2', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3']
40 ['w2', 'w2', 'w3', 'w1', 'w1']
```

Comment: Thanks for coding this up and I do agree that product would have been better choice than sum and likelihood of false positive is high with sum compare to product. Thanks !!